# How does Entity Framework reconcile differences between double and float?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am researching Entity Framework for use in a project with C# and SQL Server. As an ORM tool, Entity Framework's job is to **M**ap between the **R**elational database layer and my C# **O**bjects. Given that C# data types can be significantly different from SQL Server data types, it seems rather important for me to know the details of that mapping, yet I am finding documentation scarce. The "Mapping Details" pane tells me very little.

At the moment, I am most concerned about how Entity Framework maps C#'s *double* data type to SQL Server's *float* data type. A double may contain 3 values which are not supported by float: NaN, PositiveInfinity, and NegativeInfinity. A float may contain Null, which is not supported by double. How does Entity Framework reconcile these differences?

Edit:

Judging from the comments, I think my question is being misunderstood. I am simply asking what happens when you use Entity Framework to read or write between a C# data type and a SQL Server data type that don't have perfect equivalence. In particular, whan happens if you try to read null into a double, or write double.NaN, double.PositiveInfinity, or double.NegativeInfinity into a float? Do you get an error? Is there an implicit translation? Is there some general way of handing this type of mismatch? And where is it all documented?

Comment: Regarding `null`, there's no issue. C#: `double?` in T-SQL: `float(53)`.

Comment: Infinity isn't a value, it is a method. You just save a huge number (above infinity) in database, and when you pull it out of database infinity will again evaluate to true.